# which of following code is better performance wise in ASP.NET 2.0

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, asp.net-2.0

I have been using a datatable to display some fields from SQL 2005 database table in my website which is built in ASP.NET 2.0.

lately its been throwing timeout errors saying all the max connection pools have been reached.

here is my code using the SqlDataAdapter performing this on a Repeater OnDataItemBound.

```
#region repeater item databound
    protected void rProducts_OnItemDataBound(object source, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {

        // displaying sale and original price //
        Label lblitemid = e.Item.FindControl("itemID") as Label;
        decimal strOP;
        decimal strSP;
        string salequery = "select SaleItemNo, OriginalPrice, SalePrice, OriginalPriceRange, SalePriceRange from SaleItems where CatalogItemId='" + lblitemid.Text + "'";
        SqlConnection myconnection1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBconnection"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand SqlCmd1 = null;
        SqlCmd1 = new SqlCommand(salequery, myconnection1);
        SqlDataAdapter ad1 = new SqlDataAdapter(SqlCmd1);
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        ad1.Fill(dt1);

        Label lbloriprice = e.Item.FindControl("originalprice") as Label;
        if (dt1.Rows[0]["OriginalPrice"].ToString() == "" || dt1.Rows[0]["OriginalPrice"].ToString() == "0.00")
        {
            lbloriprice.Attributes.Add("style", "display:none");
        }
        else
        {
            strOP = Convert.ToDecimal(dt1.Rows[0]["OriginalPrice"].ToString());
            lbloriprice.Text = strOP.ToString("c");
        }

        Label lbloprange = e.Item.FindControl("opRange") as Label;
        if (dt1.Rows[0]["OriginalPriceRange"].ToString() != "")
        {
            lbloprange.Text = dt1.Rows[0]["OriginalPriceRange"].ToString();
            lbloprange.Visible = true;
            lbloriprice.Visible = false;
        }

        Label lblsaleprice = e.Item.FindControl("saleprice") as Label;
        if (dt1.Rows[0]["SalePrice"].ToString() == "" || dt1.Rows[0]["SalePrice"].ToString() == "0.00")
        {
            lblsaleprice.Attributes.Add("style", "display:none");
        }
        else if (dt1.Rows[0]["SalePriceRange"].ToString() != "")
        {
            lblsaleprice.Text = "Special <br />" + dt1.Rows[0]["SalePriceRange"].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            strSP = Convert.ToDecimal(dt1.Rows[0]["SalePrice"].ToString());
            lblsaleprice.Text = "Special <br />" + strSP.ToString("c");
        }

    }

    #endregion
```

It's throwing errors on ad1.fill(dt1)

I redesigned my code and was wondering if this will reduce or remove the errors. Please advice

```
   #region repeater item databound
    protected void rProducts_OnItemDataBound(object source, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {

        // displaying sale and original price //
        Label lblitemid = e.Item.FindControl("itemID") as Label;

        SqlDataSource SqlDataSource2 = new SqlDataSource();
        SqlDataSource2.ID = "SqlDataSource2";
        SqlDataSource2.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBconnection"].ConnectionString;
        SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = "select SaleItemNo, OriginalPrice, SalePrice, OriginalPriceRange, SalePriceRange from SaleItems where CatalogItemId='" + lblitemid.Text + "'";

        Repeater rep = e.Item.FindControl("rpt2") as Repeater;
        rep.DataSource = SqlDataSource2;
        rep.DataBind();

     }
#endregion
```

Comment: What happens when you try the new code? Nobody can guess whether this code will help, since it's hard to guess where the performance problem is.

Comment: You should look at using parameters rather than appending user input directly into your Select.  It leaves you open for SQL Injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

Your `SqlCommand`, `SqlConnection`, and `SqlDataAdapter` all need to be in `using` blocks. It's possible that your really are running  out of connections because you're not closing them in a timely manner.

---

Example of `using` blocks:

```
using (SqlConnection myconnection1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBconnection"].ConnectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand sqlCmd1 = new SqlCommand(salequery, myconnection1))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter ad1 = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd1))
        {
            dt1 = new DataTable();
            ad1.Fill(dt1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi John I thought the SqlDataAdapeter will open and close automatically, can you please give me an example of using them in blocks. Appreciate it

Comment: Hi John thanks for reply, in the above example where should open and close the connection. Appreciate it

Comment: I think that `SqlDataAdapter` will do that for you, otherwise, before the `Fill` would be good.

Comment: Thanks but how to access the datatable outside using block so I can bind the values to some labels sir